# How to capture onchange or onclick event in radio button group in PHP code?

Tags: php, html

I can't quite get this figured out and maybe I am going about it the wrong way?? (more than likely!)
Here is what I would like to do: I have a php webpage with 2 radio buttons and when someone changes the value a couple labels will change and then set a variable. I have the code written so that when the page loads, it will check the correct value based on the value stored. My thought was that in the onchange() function I will just need to get the radio button that is checked and store the variable and refresh the page? If that isn't the best method, I am open for suggestions.
Here is what I have:

```
<script> 
function displayRadioValue() { 
  var ele = document.getElementsByName('country'); 
              
  for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) { 
    if(ele[i].checked) 
    <? $COUNTRY="US"; ?>
  } 
} 
</script>
```

```html
<?php
$COUNTRY = urldecode($pluginSettings['COUNTRY']);
?>
Select your country 
<input type="radio" id="us" name="country" value="US" onclick="displayRadioValue()" <? if ($COUNTRY=="US") echo "checked"; ?>>
<label for="us">US</label>  
<input type="radio" id="other" name="country" value="Other" onclick="displayRadioValue()"<? if ($COUNTRY=="Other") echo "checked"; ?>>
<label for="other">Other</label><p/>
<? if ($COUNTRY=="US"){
echo "City:";
} else {
echo "Latitude";
}
?>  
<input type="text" name="CITY" size="16" value="<? echo $CITY; ?>"> <p>
<? if ($COUNTRY=="US"){
echo "State:";
} else {
echo "Longitude";
}
?>  
<input type="text" name="STATE" size="12" value="<? echo $STATE; ?>"> <p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking.  You cannot mix PHP and Javascript as they execute at completely different times on different machines... You need to either complete a new page load or form submission to communicate between the two.  If you do not want to load the page again, look into AJAX to transfer data between the browser and the server.

Comment: Can I accomplish what I want using just PHP? Or was the issue you were talking about in mixing PHP and JS was the PHP call in the function? Is there a way to populate a PHP variable in the function?

Comment: Instead of displayRadioValue trying to set a php variable, it needs to submit a form and pass that data to PHP in a new request to the server.  PHP can then pass that information back to the browser if needed to set the checked attribute.  You have a lot of crap in this example and I still don't understand what you are trying to do.  What is `urldecode($pluginSettings['COUNTRY'])` and where did it come from?

Comment: OK, I am lost with your recommendations, sorry. 
$COUNTRY = urldecode($pluginSettings['COUNTRY']); will get the value for $COUNTRY from a settings file, that part is functioning.
Maybe I shoud go one step at a time. The Radio buttons are to select if you are in the US or Other country. There are two textboxes to input data. If you are in the US the label for the boxes should say City and State, if you are in another country, then they need to say Latitude and Longitude. How can I get that to change with PHP?

Comment: If you want to get them to change using PHP _only_, then you would have to submit your form first, after the user chose a different radio button. This should probably be done on the client side instead.

Comment: I do not need to use PHP only, the base page is php but open for the best options.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
give the same id to both radio inputs like this 

<input type="radio" id="us" name="country" value="US" onclick="displayRadioValue()" <? if ($COUNTRY=="US") echo "checked"; ?>>
<label for="us">US</label>  
<input type="radio" id="us" name="country" value="Other" onclick="displayRadioValue()"<? if ($COUNTRY=="Other") echo "checked"; ?>>



if (document.getElementById('us').checked) {
  country = document.getElementById('us').value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this bro

```
if(ele[i].is(':checked'))
```

this return true if radio button is checked else false

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand enough to know how to even use that.